# git branch tombstones: how to mark a rebase'ed branch in git as having be dealt with

Tags: git

One of my developers does work for awhile on branch FOO1.
We deploy it to a few systems, do some experiments with it, and decide it's good, and decide to bring it into master.
Because of changes to master over the period of time, a merge would be a bad idea, so we rebase FOO1 onto master.  No problems there, master is good,
and maybe we branch/tag the result as FOO2, because FOO1 is already taken, and we don't want to delete the history.
What we would like to do is mark FOO1 as being dealt with, so that we can know that's done, as maybe have FOO20 through FOO29 which we haven't dealt with.
It could also be "FOO20" was a failure, and we never want to merge it, and want to record this fact, while not deleting the effort.

Ideally, I'd like a git way to leave a tombstone on a branch.
It should point to where the code was rebased *to*, or why it was abandoned.

I could just add new file, TOMBSTONE.md or some such and record this info.
I could also delete all the other files in that commit.  (Of course, they aren't really gone, just "git branch FOO1_lazarus FOO1^"...)

I'm wondering if there are any conventions, or maybe there are some git commands that I've missed that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You may find `git notes` useful to inform a future participant that does a `git pull` on your `FOO1` branch.

The *notes* interface allows you to apply an additional text description on an existing commit.  The *notes* will show up in `git log`, where hopefully the person pulling will notice it.  You could for example tell them to look at branch `FOO2`.

Comment: Turns out that git notes is very difficult to actually push to another repo. So while it can be used on the "main" repo to mark things, it doesn't get copied upon clone/push.